# Mathematical Calculations In .SCSS file Angular CLI Is not Working

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular7

I am not much aware of with the .scss syntax.

I am using angular CLI with .scss extension for css.

I want to return the background-color value conditional based.

```
@function getBgColor($value) {
    $modular: #{$value}%2;
    @debug $modular;
    @if($modular == 0) { 
        @return red;
    } @else {
        @return green;
    }
};

@for $i from 0 through 25 {
    .mat-column-#{$i} {
        max-width: 178px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        background-color: getBgColor(#{$i})
    }
}
```

It works fine if I try to print 2%2 without variable name.

In case of variable (In my case $value) it just simply print 1%2, 2%2, 3%2 ... 25%2 and don't do any calculations.

Comment: Do you want the first two elements is red and then green?

Comment: @TusharKumawat, No, I'm looking for the generic solution. That I can do by hard coding.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to perform mathematical operation on an interpolated value.

**Change** the following line

```
$modular: #{$value}%2;
```

**to**

```
$modular: #{$value%2};
```

Let me know how you get along with this.

Comment: I have tried this and it is not working with Angular CLI.

Comment: What does the variable print now.

Comment: It give compilation error - $modular: #{$value%2};
 ^
Undefined operation: "0 mod 2".

Comment: Can you please add your modified code here, so i can get better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need interpolation for both your statements, since you need a number, not a string.
Furthermore, you can omit the `else` condition in this case.

The following code should do what you need:

```scss
@function getBgColor($value) {
    $modular: $value % 2;
    @if($modular == 0) { 
        @return red;
    }
    @return green;
};

@for $i from 0 through 25 {
    .mat-column-#{$i} {
        max-width: 178px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        background-color: getBgColor($i)
    }
}
```

You can see the output on [SassMeister](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/d8f9dc97205e7c19634ce8a6c7b86b19).

Comment: I have tried this and it is not working with Angular CLI.

Comment: Compilation error -  
$modular: $value % 2;
 ^
Undefined operation: "0 mod 2".

Comment: The impt detail is "Interpolation returns unquoted strings that can’t be used for any further math," from: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation